# Find out what entity type an entity is?

Tags: 7, entities

How can I find out what entity type an entity is, when all I know is the entity ID?

Or is there a way I could list all the entity types on my website (or even via database)?

Comment: How did you get the entity ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't.**

Different entities use the same ID.

E.g. you can have a user with ID 42, and a node with ID 42, **and** a taxonomy term with ID 42. So just knowing the ID is 42 is not enough to know what type of entity the ID belongs to.

This is why [entity_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7) takes both the entity type and the ID as arguments.

To list all entities use [entity_get_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_get_info/7).